# how to find an equation representing a decision boundary in logistic regression

Tags: calculus, statistics, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm new to machine learning and currently working on logistic regression. but i don't know how to deal this problem. let us consider the logistic regression for a dataset $(x_n,y_n)\ (x_i \in \mathbb R^d, y_i \in \{+1,-1\})$, let $\Phi(x)=(\phi_p(x))^T$ be a p-dimensional vector of functions and $x\in\mathbb R^d$ be a parameter vector. A probabilistic model is defined as $$p(y|x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-y\theta^T\Phi(x))}$$
$$(p(+1|x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-\theta^T\Phi(x))}=\frac{\exp(\theta^T\Phi(x))}{1+\exp(\theta^T\Phi(x))},p(-1|x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(\theta^T\Phi(x))})$$
and the logistic regression estimates the parameter $\theta$ by maximizing $L(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^n\log p(y_i|x_i,\theta)$.

Then, how can I found an equation representing a decision boundary which satisfy $p(+1|x)=p(-1|y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision boundary follows from your last sentence

> Then, how can I found an equation representing a decision boundary which satisfy $p(+1|x)= p(−1|x)$?

(correcting $p(-1|y)$ to $p(-1|x)$). The decision boundary is given by the set
$$\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:p(+1|x) = p(-1|x)\right\}.$$
Then expanding the condition,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+\exp(-\theta^T\Phi(x))} &= \frac{1}{1+\exp(\theta^T\Phi(x))} \\
 1+\exp(-\theta^T\Phi(x)) &= 1+\exp(\theta^T\Phi(x)) \\
-\theta^T\phi(x) &= \theta^T\Phi(x)\\
\Rightarrow \theta^T\Phi(x) &= 0.
\end{align*}
And so the decision boundary is given by the set,
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:\theta^T\Phi(x) = 0\}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the the answer. For $x\in\mathbb R^2$ and $\Phi (x)=(x_1,x_2)^T$, is the decision boundary $\theta_1x_1=-\theta_2x_2$?

Comment: Yes, that would follow from $\theta^T\Phi(x) = 0$ .